# Dragging a rectangle in Raphael JS bounces back and forth

Tags: javascript, raphael

In this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pgschr/gcr9Ljmo/1/) I have a Raphael JS grid with a rectangle that I need to move snapped to a grid. The rectangle has four red handles in each corner, and when it moves the handles move as well.

So far I can move the rectangle around (that works fine) but when I try to move it to the left the rectangle flickers and bounces back and forth. Could the problem be that I'm setting the `x` rectangle coordinate inside the drag `move` function? Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

```
   var move = function(dx, dy) {
    rect.attr("x", ox + dx);
    rect.attr("y", oy + dy);
    leftTop.attr("x", ox1 + dx);
    leftTop.attr("y", oy1 + dy);
    rightTop.attr("x", ox2 + dx);
    rightTop.attr("y", oy2 + dy);
    leftBottom.attr("x", ox3 + dx);
    leftBottom.attr("y", oy3 + dy);
    rightBottom.attr("x", ox4 + dx);
    rightBottom.attr("y", oy4 + dy);

    if ((dx - lastdx) < 0)
        seeMoveLeft(rect, leftTop, rightTop,
                 leftBottom, rightBottom);

    lastdx = dx; 

};

var up = function() {};

rect.drag(move, start, up);


var seeMoveLeft = function (rect, leftTop, rightTop,
                 leftBottom, rightBottom){
    var left = rect.attr('x');
    // find next left grid
    var found = false;
    var min = left - 40;
    for (var i=left; i>=min; i--){
       if (i % 40 == 0) {
          found = true;
          break;
       }
    }

    if (found) {
        var diff = left - i;
        rect.attr('x', i);
        var lt = leftTop.attr('x');
        leftTop.attr('x', lt - diff);
        var rt = rightTop.attr('x');
        rightTop.attr('x', rt - diff);
        var lb = leftBottom.attr('x'); 
        leftBottom.attr('x', lb - diff);
        var rb = rightBottom.attr('x');
        rightBottom.attr('x', rb - diff);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you set the new x of rect here:

```
rect.attr("x", ox + dx);
```

Then you modify it here:

```
if ((dx - lastdx) < 0)
        seeMoveLeft(rect, leftTop, rightTop,
                 leftBottom, rightBottom);
```

But since move function is based on the **mousemove** event, sometimes, you'll get the same **dx** value 2 times in a row. This is normal with **mousemove** event, especially if you move slow. You can try it below, each time the **clientX** stays the same, the window will turn green.

```js
var lastClientX;
window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {

  if (lastClientX && e.clientX === lastClientX) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  } else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  }

  lastClientX = e.clientX;

})
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height 100%;
}
```

What happens in your case when you have 2 consecutive identical **dx** is that `x - lastdx` won't validate and so the position won't be adjusted and will stay at `rect.attr("x", ox + dx);`. So first move event, the position is adjusted to the grid with **seeMoveLeft**, next, the position changes but isn't adjusted because **dx** is not smaller than **lastdx**, it's equal. Hence the flicker you see.

Simplest way to correct, would be to skip the positionning if **dx** is the same as **lastdx**. Like this:

```
if(lastdx !== dx){
    rect.attr("x", ox + dx);
    leftTop.attr("x", ox1 + dx);
    rightTop.attr("x", ox2 + dx);
    leftBottom.attr("x", ox3 + dx);
    rightBottom.attr("x", ox4 + dx);
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ce7sh9ov/1/